# What is the shortest keystroke to yank a C/C++ identifier in Vim?

Tags: vim

Vim has the `*` (star) command which searches forward to the next (or *n*th, if a count is provided) occurrence of the word under the cursor. Using that command for `word`, one gets the `\<word\>` pattern in the `/` register (which holds the most recent search pattern).

The difference between searching for `word` and `\<word\>` is that the first pattern matches `word` in `wordfoo`, `bar_word`, etc., while the second does not. This is because `\<` and `\>` matches the beginning and end of a word, respectively.

I would like to know what is the best way to yank a word, similarly to how `*` does it (or `#`, its backwards counterpart), but without changing the cursor position.

Comment: `yw` places just `word` without the escaped angled braskets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to put together `\<`, `\>`, and the word under the cursor to make
a search pattern in a register, why not explicitly do that?

```
:let @/ = '\<'..expand('<cword>')..'\>'
```

(Change `@/` to a reference to any other register, if necessary.)

For convenience, you can make a shortcut for it:

```
:noremap <silent> ,/ :let @/='\<'..expand('<cword>')..'\>'<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks! Extra points for the `expand('<cword>')` thing which I didn't know. =)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the wrong track by looking at yank options, I think you need to write a quick macro that searches for the word in the register and add the word boundary markers there. Then you can use `yiw`, `yaw`, `yw` and all the other various standard yank commands, and your macro will deal with the adding boundaries to the search.

Comment: `yiw`  and `yaw` change the cursor position, btw.

Answer (score 1):

The `yw` command yanks from the cursor position to the *end* of the word. Using [Vim text objects](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select), the `yaw` command yanks the whole word on which the cursor is positioned, even if the cursor is not positioned at the start of the word.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but notice the importance of the escaped brackets around the word since I plan to use the content of the register for a future search.

Comment: If you're looking for the angle brackets, I think the yank command might not be the right command. All yank commands extract text *from the buffer*, and "escaped angle brackets" are not part of the text in the buffer.

Comment: Yank was one way to describe it, I want to put the pattern in a register.

Answer (score 1):

`*` will search for the identifier, and also place the searchterm in the `/` register. You can access it by pressing `<Ctrl-R>/` in input-mode, or `"/p` in normal mode.

This will unfortunately move the cursor to the next match. You can save the current position using marks. Save the current position with `ma`, and restore it with `` `a ``.

The final command is `` ma*`a ``

Comment: Use the backtick instead of ' otherwise the jump-to-mark will go to the start of the line.